# ActiveCollab API - How do I sort assigned subtasks in their display order?

Tags: activecollab

Sifting through the ActiveCollab API, it seems like subtasks are missing a `position` field, when fetched through the `reports/run` endpoint. When fetching subtasks through the `/projects/<PROJECT_ID>/tasks/<task_id>` endpoint, they *do* have a `position` field.

Looking up a list of my own tasks (such as `/reports/run`, with the `type` query parameter set to "AssignmentFilter", and the `user_filter` parameter set to "selected_`<USER_ID>`", I get a list of assigned tasks, as well as assigned subtasks. But while the tasks have a "position" field, the subtasks don't seem to have anything that might help me infer their display ordering (i.e. the same order in which they appear in the web app).

Am I missing some other way of inferring the display order of subtasks, when fetched through the `reports/run` endpoint?

---

On a somewhat related note: the `reports/run` endpoint also returns some fields with a different type. I've noticed `position` and `task_number` changing type, from integer to string. Like so: `position: 1` to `position: "1"`.